# Probability in a deck of cards

Tags: probability, combinatorics

> A card is removed from a deck of $52$ cards. Without knowing what this card was, what is the probability that the next card removed is a spade?

Comment: Can you think of a way to split the problem into two cases?

Comment: Three things are considered when determining a good question: [context, context, context](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9960).

Comment: It is worth pointing out that the longer more frustrating answer of breaking into cases yields the same result as the intuitive answer in this case: the intuitive answer being that it doesn't matter that the top card was removed, it will be $\frac{13}{52}$ just as though the card being drawn was the real top card instead.

Answer (score 1):

Card removed is spade: $\frac14\cdot\frac{12}{51}=\frac3{51}$

Card removed is not spade: $\frac34\cdot\frac{13}{51}=\frac{39}{204}$

Therefore the probability is $\frac3{51}+\frac{39}{204}=\frac{51}{204}=\frac14$